# Blender to Autocad, units issue

Tags: units

When I export from Blender to Autocad as DXF, it does not keep my units the same, I choose meters for example, when I export to auto cad its says 2.000, when i check the units it says unit-less, when i try to change it to mm, it does not change, however it was supposed to say 2000 mm, rather than stuck on 2.000 ?